# How to set a configuration parameter using service messages in the project file

Tags: c#, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

**Description**

TeamCity side: I defined a *Configuration Parameter* named `major.minor.patch` with an empty value. This can be accessed in TeamCity build steps as `%major.minor.patch%`

Visual Studio side:

In my `.csproj` file I added the code below to set `major.minor.patch` to the current version of my assembly:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TEAMCITY_BUILD_PROPERTIES_FILE)' == ''">
  <TeamCityBuild>true</TeamCityBuild>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Other stuff... -->   

<Target Name="TeamCity" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TeamCityBuild)' == 'true'">
<GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)">
   <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyItentity"/>
</GetAssemblyIdentity>
<Message Text="##teamcity[setParameter name='major.minor.patch' value='%(AssemblyIdentity.Version)'"/>
```

**Problem**

However, this code seems not working since the Parameter is still empty.

I also tried defining my parameter as an environment variable: `env.maor.minor.patch`, still no chance.

**Question**

- How can I do this?
- How to set a Configuration Parameter in TeamCity to my assembly version in my C# project?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Importance of the Message to High

```
Message Text="##teamcity[setParameter name='major.minor.patch' value='%(AssemblyIdentity.Version)'" Importance="high" />
```